# show the count of records found in the asp listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, count

I thought this would be eaiser, but I can't seem to find a simple solution for it.  I have a listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVSearchResults" runat="server" DataSourceID="DSSearchResults">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PostDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("post_date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <th runat="server">Found Rows</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th1" runat="server">Post Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="15">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" ButtonCount="10" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

My Datasource:

```
 <asp:Sqldatasource ID="DSSearchResults"  runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CDRConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="usp_Search"
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    >
 </asp:Sqldatasource>
```

What I would like to do is display the count of records found. So the list view would appear like:

```
Found 123 records
Post Date
6/1/13
6/2/13
etc.
```

I tried playing with the Container, but that didn't seem to offer anything, googled, also couldn't find much.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Just place a literal (better than your label) above the Listview (outside the markup) and set its tekst value when DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
HtmlTableCell th = (HtmlTableCell)LVSearchResults.FindControl("Th1");
th.InnerText = "Found " + LVSearchResults.Items.Count.ToString() + " items.";
```

But because you are using the `DataPager` control, it will always return 15. So maybe you want to update the cell using data from the datasource instead. Maybe if you show the DataSource I can tell you how to get it from it.

Comment: Thanks, I also had this problem with using the Datapager.  I have put my datasource, it's pretty simple, just a sql stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

it's so easy
Use the code below in your codebehind to get all records count

Ctype (listview1.FindControl ("DataPager1"),DataPager).TotalRowCount

Instead of listview1 , just write the ID of ur listview . . .

Good luck